# Expedia EAN Database Query

Tags: database, api, local-storage

From high level usage, please help me with the following.

I am looking to utilize the database from Expedia EAN. It recommends you update the database weekly via  cron job.

On the home page of my application, if I have a enter your location/dates/number of guests, and search for hotel availability, should I be fetching data via this local database or from via the live API?

It doesn't seem to make sense to fetch this from the local database, as how will it be up to date in terms of use availability. If that's the case, it doesn't really seem useful to use the local database unless its just for browsing hotels?

Thanks

Comment: Use the local copy of the database for any browsing activity your visitors perform. Query the live API for real time data like availability.

Answer (score 0):

Expedia's EAN provides the Database with pseudo-static (slowly changing) data such as hotel's location, address, images, description etc. These are the ones to be downloaded as files once per day or so.

Then they also provide dynamic data such as availability and prices via their API. Those data surely can be fetched at the time of request.